# Elastic Beanstalk - Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to use a git link in order to install a package which is on github. For this, I included the following line in my requirements.txt file:

```
[-e] git+https://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-clients#egg=python
```

But I get the following error when I run `eb deploy -v`

```
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What's the right way to list a requirement like that? Pip version of the instance is 9.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had had success installing it using the following format in `requirements.txt`:

```
git+git://github.com/deribit/deribit-api-clients.git#egg=openapi-client&subdirectory=python
```

For tests I used Python 3.6 Amazon Linux 1 EB environment.

p.s.
`git` is needed for that, but I guess you already are installing it.